# List of Groups Plot in line graph In R Issue

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, analysis

I have a list of groups that separates data by zipcode and months. I am having trouble plotting the data in a line graph.

```
data <- read.csv("./data/rental_12_11_2015_365.csv")
data$Listing.Contract.Date <- as.Date(data$Listing.Contract.Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
data$Month_Int <- as.numeric(strftime(data$Listing.Contract.Date,"%m"))
data$Month_Char <- month.abb[data$Month_Int]
groups_zipcode <- with(data, split(data, list(Zip.Code, Month_Char)))
summaryofgroups <- lapply(groups_zipcode, function(group){nrow(group)})
```

ggplot(data = groups_zipcode, aes(x=Month_Char, y=summaryofgroups, group=Zip.Code, col=Zip.Code)) + geom_line()

The output is what I have below but for all the months etc. I did not paste everything. The ggplot is producing "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list".

```
$`75013.Apr`
[1] 11

$`75025.Apr`
[1] 39

$`75035.Apr`
[1] 71

$`75070.Apr`
[1] 103

$`75071.Apr`
[1] 43

$`75075.Apr`
[1] 15

$`75093.Apr`
[1] 13

$`75013.Aug`
[1] 18

$`75025.Aug`
[1] 39

$`75035.Aug`
[1] 80

$`75070.Aug`
[1] 93

$`75071.Aug`
[1] 49

$`75075.Aug`
[1] 16

$`75093.Aug`
[1] 19
```

Solution:

Hi I was able to find the solution. This was what I was trying to do. Good luck to anyone else in a similar situation.

```
 inventory_graph <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x=Month_Char, fill = as.factor(Zip.Code))) + geom_histogram(position = "dodge")
```

Comment: FYI, you can write that last line as `summaryofgroups <- lapply(groups_zipcode, nrow)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is in the right format, you can do this very simply using `ggplot`:

```
#Some fake data in the same format as you pasted
fake_data <- data.frame("Zip" = factor(rep(c(12345, 98765, 56473), 4)),
                    "Month" = factor(rep(c("April", "May", "June", "July"), each=3), levels=c("April", "May", "June", "July")),
                    "Count" = sample(20:50, 12))
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = fake_data, aes(x=Month, y=Count, group=Zip, col=Zip)) + geom_line()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I am still having some trouble. Do you mean something like this? ggplot(data = groups_zipcode, aes(x=Month_Char, y=summaryofgroups, group=Zip.Code, col=Zip.Code)) +geom_line(). I am not sure how to get the summaryofgroups information linked up. It is the list that contains the count of zipcode inventory.